# How do I set radio buttons so that I can have different variables on each one of them

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am currently working on a project where I need to display a list from sqlite and I need to place a set of radio button on each entry. I just need to differentiate the variable for each radio button so I can use them separately. Here is my code:

```
def load_mainFrame():
main_frame.tkraise()
confusionMatrixData = fetch_db()

documents = []
categories = []
buttonGridPlacementIterator = 0;
r = StringVar()

for i in confusionMatrixData:
    document = i[0]
    category = i[1]
    documents.append(document)
    categories.append(category)

trueValueLabel = tk.Label(second_frame, text="True Value", font=('Arial', 15))
documentLabel = tk.Label(second_frame, text="Document", font=('Arial', 15))
categoryLabel = tk.Label(second_frame, text="Category", font=('Arial', 15))
positiveLabel = tk.Label(second_frame, text="Positive", font=('Arial', 15))
negativeLabel = tk.Label(second_frame, text="Negative", font=('Arial', 15))
neutralLabel = tk.Label(second_frame, text="Neutral", font=('Arial', 15))

trueValueLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx=10, pady=5)
documentLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
categoryLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx=10, pady=5)
positiveLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx=10, pady=5)
negativeLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 4, padx=10, pady=5)
neutralLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 5, padx=10, pady=5)

for i in range(len(documents)):
    print (i, documents[i])
    tk.Label(
        second_frame,
        text=documents[i],
        font=("TkMenuFont", 10)
        ).grid(row = i+2, column = 1, pady=5)

for i in range(len(categories)):
    tk.Label(
        second_frame,
        text=categories[i],
        font=("TkMenuFont", 10)
        ).grid(row = i+2, column = 2, pady=5)
    Radiobutton(second_frame, text="", variable=r, value="positive", command=lambda: clicked(r.get())).grid(row= i+2, column = 3)
    Radiobutton(second_frame, text="", variable=r, value="negative", command=lambda: clicked(r.get())).grid(row= i+2, column = 4)
    Radiobutton(second_frame, text="", variable=r, value="neutral", command=lambda: clicked(r.get())).grid(row= i+2, column = 5)
```

Comment: Please include some sample data in your example (no more than 2-3 rows), and fix the broken documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all  you need to do is create a separate variable for each row. You didn't provide a runnable example so I'm unable to test this code. In general, though, each set of radiobuttons needs to share a variable. It is this shared variable that allows tkinter to know which radiobuttons should be treated as a group.

```
radiobuttons = []
for i in range(len(categories)):
    var = tk.StringVar()
    radiobuttons.append(var)
    ...
    Radiobutton(second_frame, text="", variable=var, value="positive", command=lambda: clicked(var.get())).grid(row= i+2, column = 3)
    Radiobutton(second_frame, text="", variable=var, value="negative", command=lambda: clicked(var.get())).grid(row= i+2, column = 4)
    Radiobutton(second_frame, text="", variable=var, value="neutral", command=lambda: clicked(var.get())).grid(row= i+2, column = 5)
```